# After scraping data from a URL using readHTMLTable, how can I convert the result to a data frame?

Tags: r, xml-parsing, rvest

I've tried all sorts of different manipulations, but my basic problem is this:

```
url<- "http://www.ref.org.uk/fuel/tablebysp.php?valdate=2015-03-08"
data <- readHTMLTable(url,header = TRUE,as.data.frame =TRUE,which=2)
typeof(data)
```

My data looks great, but I cannot coerce it into a data frame. I don't know what is stopping me.

Comment: I should have looked at your question more closely (and tried your code) before posting my answer. You do indeed have a `data.frame` from your code. Try `class(data)` vs `typeof(data)`.  Take a look at the code in `page(data.frame)` to see what R is actually returning when it creates a `data.frame`.

Comment: OK, I can see that I do have a `data.frame` from my code. But I still can't get my data to behave the way it looks like it should. I can't subset and plot columns, because it looks like my columns are factors. When I include `colClasses=c("character",rep("numeric",15)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE` into the arguments for `readHTMLTable` it has to coerce NAs.

Comment: try adding `, stringsAsFactors=FALSE` instead of `colClasses`. There are commas in many of the column values. I provided an expanded example of  that and some cleanup code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the post comments, your code actually works fine. You can get strings instead of factors with:

```
url<- "http://www.ref.org.uk/fuel/tablebysp.php?valdate=2015-03-08"
data <- readHTMLTable(url, header=TRUE, as.data.frame=TRUE, which=2, 
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Below is how to do this with the `rvest` package, which really shines for this, especially when there are multiple tables or weirdly nested ones. And, there's some `dplyr`

In this case, there is more than one table and the second one is what you want. Thankfully, it's pretty well-formed. The code below extracts all the tables from the page (with CSS selectors) then uses the handy `magrittr` `extract2`to avoid what would be weird/ugly `[[]]` usage.

The piping idiom (which started with `magrittr` and is now used in much of the hadleyverse) "pushes" or "flows" data from left to right vs "pops" data out from nested parenthesis calls.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

pg <- html("http://www.ref.org.uk/fuel/tablebysp.php?valdate=2015-03-08")
dat <- pg %>% html_nodes("table") %>% extract2(2) %>% html_table(header=TRUE)
glimpse(dat)

## Observations: 48
## Variables:
## $ SD         (chr) "2015-03-08", "2015-03-08", "2015-03-08", "2015-03-08", "2015-03-08", "2015-03-08", "...
## $ SP         (int) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24...
## $ Gas        (chr) "3,467", "3,522", "3,594", "3,529", "2,811", "2,538", "2,520", "2,489", "2,498", "2,5...
## $ Coal       (chr) "8,261", "8,062", "7,876", "7,437", "6,751", "6,799", "6,621", "6,428", "6,586", "6,2...
## $ Nuclear    (chr) "7,495", "7,553", "7,641", "7,676", "7,674", "7,672", "7,676", "7,677", "7,672", "7,6...
## $ Hydro      (int) 737, 729, 666, 651, 646, 647, 645, 648, 658, 729, 734, 736, 740, 738, 740, 741, 751, ...
## $ Net Pumped (chr) "-438", "-84", "-504", "-860", "-1,092", "-1,118", "-1,396", "-1,700", "-1,606", "-1,...
## $ Wind       (chr) "4,675", "4,795", "4,623", "4,572", "4,647", "4,570", "4,377", "4,445", "4,602", "4,5...
## $ OCGT       (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
## $ Oil        (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
## $ Biomass    (chr) "1,078", "1,079", "1,081", "1,048", "1,005", "1,022", "1,086", "1,035", "1,072", "1,0...
## $ French Int (chr) "480", "480", "680", "678", "1,614", "1,626", "1,532", "1,536", "772", "772", "504", ...
## $ Dutch Int  (chr) "860", "852", "874", "838", "850", "866", "848", "830", "830", "866", "862", "862", "...
## $ NI Int     (int) 22, -72, 2, -16, -30, -50, 4, 4, -122, -138, -108, -114, -2, 16, 24, 24, 28, -30, -42...
## $ Eire Int   (int) 170, 190, 142, 142, 142, 114, 114, 114, 114, 112, 88, 50, 16, 16, 16, 42, 18, -72, -1...
## $ Net Supply (chr) "26,807", "27,106", "26,675", "25,695", "25,018", "24,686", "24,027", "23,506", "23,0...
```

You can alternatively do:

```
html_table(extract2(html_nodes(pg, "table"), 2), header=TRUE)
```

if you don't like or generally use pipes.

You can then do some basic cleanup of columns to get useful numeric/date values:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(SD=as.Date(SD),
         Gas=as.numeric(gsub(",", "", Gas)),
         Coal=as.numeric(gsub(",", "", Coal)),
         Nuclear=as.numeric(gsub(",", "", Nuclear)),
         `Net Pumped`=as.numeric(gsub(",", "", `Net Pumped`)),
         `Wind`=as.numeric(gsub(",", "", `Wind`)),
         Biomass=as.numeric(gsub(",", "", Biomass)),
         `French Int`=as.numeric(gsub(",", "", `French Int`)),
         `Dutch Int`=as.numeric(gsub(",", "", `Dutch Int`)),
         `Net Supply`=as.numeric(gsub(",", "", `Net Supply`))) -> dat

glimpse(dat)

## Observations: 48
## Variables:
## $ SD         (date) 2015-03-08, 2015-03-08, 2015-03-08, 2015-03-08, 2015-03-08, 2015-03-08, 2015-03-08, ...
## $ SP         (int) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24...
## $ Gas        (dbl) 3467, 3522, 3594, 3529, 2811, 2538, 2520, 2489, 2498, 2543, 2531, 2522, 2627, 2729, 2...
## $ Coal       (dbl) 8261, 8062, 7876, 7437, 6751, 6799, 6621, 6428, 6586, 6229, 6194, 6299, 6455, 6639, 6...
## $ Nuclear    (dbl) 7495, 7553, 7641, 7676, 7674, 7672, 7676, 7677, 7672, 7670, 7673, 7677, 7677, 7681, 7...
## $ Hydro      (int) 737, 729, 666, 651, 646, 647, 645, 648, 658, 729, 734, 736, 740, 738, 740, 741, 751, ...
## $ Net Pumped (dbl) -438, -84, -504, -860, -1092, -1118, -1396, -1700, -1606, -1632, -1344, -1052, -1342,...
## $ Wind       (dbl) 4675, 4795, 4623, 4572, 4647, 4570, 4377, 4445, 4602, 4570, 4529, 4512, 4312, 3976, 3...
## $ OCGT       (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
## $ Oil        (int) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
## $ Biomass    (dbl) 1078, 1079, 1081, 1048, 1005, 1022, 1086, 1035, 1072, 1086, 1084, 1085, 1086, 1082, 1...
## $ French Int (dbl) 480, 480, 680, 678, 1614, 1626, 1532, 1536, 772, 772, 504, 502, 1598, 1602, 1878, 188...
## $ Dutch Int  (dbl) 860, 852, 874, 838, 850, 866, 848, 830, 830, 866, 862, 862, 884, 846, 942, 914, 1032,...
## $ NI Int     (int) 22, -72, 2, -16, -30, -50, 4, 4, -122, -138, -108, -114, -2, 16, 24, 24, 28, -30, -42...
## $ Eire Int   (int) 170, 190, 142, 142, 142, 114, 114, 114, 114, 112, 88, 50, 16, 16, 16, 42, 18, -72, -1...
## $ Net Supply (dbl) 26807, 27106, 26675, 25695, 25018, 24686, 24027, 23506, 23076, 22807, 22747, 23079, 2...
```

Comment: I know the SO Overlords don't like code only answers, but I certainly like them when they are so clear and compact.

Comment: Can you explain why the magrittr piping convention goes left to right while the R assignment convention is right to left? Is it just to mimic Unix convention or is there something deeper?

Comment: The piping definitely has roots in Unix and it's meant to make code cleaner and make parameter usage clearer (they can get lost in deep parenthetical nesting). I also included the version w/o pipes.

Comment: Apologies ( if needed) for an OT question, but do you use magrittr/dplyr code in the R tutorial in your InfoSec book?

Comment: No. I am/we (coauthor) are a firm believer in needing to know "base R". We avoided most of these new fangled things in the book. I can't fathom doing "good/advanced R" without knowing base _really_ well. And, to debug any of the hadleyverse requires a full knowledge of base (IMO). I still end up doing much of my initial quick exploratory data plots with `plot` and `boxplot` for speed.